# User Access Rights or Permissions to features of a web app patterns or best practices

Tags: c#, permissions, design-patterns

I have to implement user access rights or permissions to different features in a web app.  For example; if the user cannot view reports, do not show the Report menu, or if the user cannot create new employees, do not show the New button.  These user access rights or permission would be turn on/off UI elements.  I'm looking for patterns or best practices to accomplish this.

I was thinking on just creating a function called bool UserHasPermission(Activity).  The function will be inside the UserSecurity Class.  I'll pass some activity, like "Reports" and true or false.  If true, then I will do manuoption.visible = true or the other way around.

Would this be a good idea?  The only thing it bother me if that I'll have to pass a string with the activity "Reports".

Thank you your opinion/advice,

Aldo

Answer (score 2):

Instead of reinventing the wheel, try and repackage the `System.Web.Security`

`RoleProvider` (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.roleprovider.aspx)

and

`MembershipProvider` (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.membershipprovider.aspx) classes included with ASP.NET.

You can then leverage the pre-written and supported interfaces e.g. `IsInRole("blah");`

Tutorials:

http://www.15seconds.com/issue/050216.htm

http://www.devx.com/asp/Article/29256/0/page/3